# SQL Query changing the middle numbers to XXX. Ex: 9744XXXXX3544

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select AccountNumber From Sample_table
```

Above is my sample query.

The Current output is  9744123453544.

how can i make it    9744XXXXX3544

Comment: Column data type? Always same number of characters?

Comment: Kenneth, next time, when you accept an answer, you might have a look at the time of publication. @TriV posted exactly the same answer, but 2 hours earlier. It is even better fitting to your question, as it answers your issue in an tabular context, while the accepted answer shows this for a variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be executed using STUFF function in a very simple way.

```
DECLARE @accountNumber VARCHAR(50) 

SET @accountNumber = '9744123453544' 

SELECT Stuff(@accountNumber, 5, 5, 'XXXXX')
```

Since this is fixed for the account number length.

Comment: This answer is exactly the same as TriV's - but quite some time later...

Answer (score 3):

You could use `STUFF` like this

```
Select STUFF(AccountNumber,5,5,'XXXXX')  from yourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value length is fixed this will helps you

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(200)
SET @String = '9744123453544'
SELECT STUFF(@String, 5, LEN(@String) - 8, REPLICATE('X', LEN(@String) - 8)) AS HideValue
```

OutPut

```
HideValue
---------
9744XXXXX3544
```

Comment: A good approach (+1 from my side), but you might use `REPLICATE` to get the appropriate count of "X", as you are trying to do this for different string lengths dynamically...

Comment: @Shnugo Thank you for suggestion REPLICATE has not come in to mind .i am glad that i got suggestion from you sir

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing it in a UDF for the sake of clarity and reusability, but if you want to do it inline in SQL, here's how you could do it:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(AccountNumber, 1, 4) +
         REPLICATE('X', LEN(AccountNumber) - 8) +
         SUBSTRING(AccountNumber, LEN(AccountNumber) - 3, LEN(AccountNumber))
FROM Sample_Table
```

Here's how you can do it as a UDF and have varying configurations:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CensorString(@str VARCHAR(200), @show_left INT = 4, @show_right INT = 4)
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret VARCHAR(200) = '';

    IF @show_left > 0
        SET @ret = @ret + SUBSTRING(@str, 1, @show_left);

    SET @ret = @ret + REPLICATE('X', LEN(@str) - @show_left - @show_right);

    IF @show_right > 0
        SET @ret = @ret + SUBSTRING(@str, LEN(@ret) + 1, LEN(@str));

    RETURN @ret;
END
GO

SELECT dbo.CensorString('112233445566778899', 0, 4);
SELECT dbo.CensorString('112233445566778899', default, default);
```

Output:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX8899  
1122XXXXXXXXXX8899
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL Server 2016+ try using dynamic data masking feature. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking).